# Performance Difference between using ToList() vs. new List(IEnumerable<T>)

Tags: c#

I was curious as to the performance impact of using ToList() on an IEnumerable versus just calling the List Constructor 'List(IEnumerable)'.

Example:

```
int[] testArray = new int[10];
var list = testArray.ToList();
```

vs.

```
int[] testArray = new int[10];
var list = new List<int>(testArray);
```

Is there any performance impact or best practice in using one over the other?

I've taken over an application where the controller methods I'm calling returns an array, but the views I have are expecting a List.

Comment: Even if there is (which I'm very doubtful of), it's almost certainly not going to be the bottleneck in your program.

Comment: Yea, I'm not expecting the performance hit to be very noticeable, if at all, but I am always looking for ways to increase performance, because the system I'm working on gets millions of hits a day, and performance is an issue.  If there is not performance issues, is there at least a best practice to use?

Comment: Profile first.  Always profile first.  The best practice is likely whatever is more readable in the context of the code.

Comment: I do always try to profile if possible.  I even has a VS extension to help notify me if any methods are getting too unwieldy.  In this case, both situations are just as easily readable, so it definitely comes down to any hit on performance, if it exists.

Comment: I would use `ToList` because it works on many different `IEnumerable` types.  This allows you to change your test array to a different enumerable type if you so choose to in the future, leading to less fragile code.  I also find the syntax of `ToList` more obvious than the constructor argument.

Comment: This was more of a conceptual question vs. a specific coding issue.  Felt more appropriate in this forum.  This question was about performance, but also about best coding practice if performance wasn't an issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a million users, so I can't help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer will depend upon the specifics of the implementation.

Comment: I have a DB table with more than 3 millions of records. While fetching and returning records to UI, when I fetch the records using Linq query and convert those records using new List<T>() it takes more time compared to using ToList<T>() at the end of Linq query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like others already said, most of the time the best practice is to do what is more readable (which I think here means using `ToList()`). Both ways do exactly the same thing, so you should expect that their performance to be very similar.

If profiling shows that this is the code you need to optimize, then you should try it both ways and measure which one is faster.

And looking at the source code (in the case of .Net base libraries, you can look at [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) or use a decompiler) might help too. [`ToList`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#e276d6892241255b) looks like this:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

So, its performance should be the same as `new List`, plus one `null` check and one method call. But both of the additions are likely to be optimized away.

Comment: Methods that contain a throw statement are not optimized away.  Too disruptive to the exception's stack trace.

Comment: Still boils down to 'both are virtually the same'.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm actually doing a null check on my end anyways with what is in place. I'll remember in the future that it is basically if I want/need the null check or not and which format profiles better in the code I'm working on.

Comment: @DanielShaw Well, `new List` also does the `null` check by itself. So it doesn't matter from that point of view either.

Comment: For some reason I found `new List<int>(collection.Select(x => x.Id))` performance 2.5-3x times slower than `collection.Select(x => x.Id).ToList()` in Unity.

Comment: @bashis That's odd. Are you sure you're measuring it correctly? Keep in mind that writing correct microbenchmarks is really hard.

Comment: @svick I'm not using Benchmark.NET because it's currently not supported for unity so I use `Stopwatch`. What I do is measure a total of 1000 attempts to create a `List<int>` out of another `List<Element>` containing 1000 elements where `Element` is basically a class wrapping an `int` property.  I measure that under Mono runtime (.NET Standard 2.1). I get stable results with LINQ being faster than constructor call. I don't know why. I also noticed that I get equal time when running `ToList()` and when pre-allocating capacity in `List` ctor and then `Add`ing elements manually in a loop.