# LINQ Grouping a query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

I initially asked a question as i was getting and error with a similar query and i found help in fixing that, I now have an question / need for a little help understanding how to formulate the correct group for a return, this will be for WEB API and need the output grouped in a certain way and i cant quite get there.

Class -

```
public class GoodInWarehouseBM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Pallet Number
    /// </summary>
    public string pallet_identifier { get; set; }

    public List<ShipmentItems> shipment_items { get; set; }

    public class ShipmentItems
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// SKU Code
        /// </summary>
        public string sku { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Products on Pallet
        /// </summary>
        public decimal stock_qty { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Description of Item
        /// </summary>
        public string description { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Method -

```
public IQueryable<IGrouping<string, GoodInWarehouseBM>> GetWarehouseToStoreList(string storeId)
{
    var entity = (from consighdrs in mi9TestEntities.consighdrs
                  join consigdests in mi9TestEntities.consigdests on consighdrs.consignment equals consigdests.consignment
                  join consigliness in mi9TestEntities.consiglines on consigdests.condestint equals consigliness
                      .condestint
                  join productcodess in mi9TestEntities.productcodes on consigliness.varint equals productcodess.varint
                  join products in mi9TestEntities.products on productcodess.prodint equals products.prodint
                  where consigdests.destination == storeId && consighdrs.status == "T"
                  select new GoodInWarehouseBM()
                  {
                      pallet_identifier = consigdests.consignment,
                      shipment_items = new List<GoodInWarehouseBM.ShipmentItems>
                    {new GoodInWarehouseBM.ShipmentItems
                    {
                        sku = productcodess.variantcode,
                        stock_qty = consigliness.issueqty,
                        description = products.proddesc
                    }}

                  }).GroupBy(x => x.pallet_identifier);

    return entity;
}
```

ouput -

```
[
    [
        {
            "pallet_identifier": "FS300057058",
            "shipment_items": [
                {
                    "sku": "051657",
                    "stock_qty": 1,
                    "description": "BELT 1.25\" 5028"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "pallet_identifier": "FS300057058",
            "shipment_items": [
                {
                    "sku": "10121781",
                    "stock_qty": 1,
                    "description": "SLAZ CREW SWEAT"
                }
            ]
        },
```

wanted output -

```
[
  {
    "pallet_identifier": "FS300057058",
    "shipment_items": [
            {
              "sku": "051657",
              "stock_qty": 1,
              "description": "BELT 1.25\" 5028"
            },
            {
              "sku": "10121781",
              "stock_qty": 1,
              "description": "SLAZ CREW SWEAT"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I seem to be wrapping myself up here in how to actually get that result, any help and pointers will be gratefully accepted.

Comment: could you please show how did you consume the above `GetWarehouseToStoreList` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select you grouped result after applying grouping like

```
...
}).GroupBy(x => x.pallet_identifier)
  .Select(x => new GoodInWarehouseBM { pallet_identifier = x.Key, shipment_items = x.ToList() });
```

And change you method return type to `List<GoodInWarehouseBM>` instead of `IQueryable<IGrouping<string, GoodInWarehouseBM>>`

Or you can use traditional linq query,

```
var entity = (from consighdrs in mi9TestEntities.consighdrs
...
...
...
where consigdests.destination == storeId && consighdrs.status == "T"
group new { consigdests, productcodess, consigliness, products } by consigdests.consignment into grp
select new GoodInWarehouseBM
{
    pallet_identifier = grp.Key,
    shipment_items = grp.Select(a => new ShipmentItems
    {
        sku  = a.productcodess.variantcode,
        stock_qty = a.consigliness.issueqty,
        description = a.products.proddesc
    })  
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but im unable to select a.productcodess.variantcode etc, do i need to add them to the group to be able to select?

Comment: **Answer updated**,  try it and let me know. kindly notice this line => `group new { consigdests, productcodess, consigliness, products} by consigdests.consignment into grp`

Comment: That has worked perfectly! I had to change public List<ShipmentItems> into and IEnumerable but then it worked, thanks for the help, I now have learnt how to do this in the future.

Comment: for List<ShipmentItems> you can add `.ToList()` to inner select then you will not longer need `IEnumerable`

Comment: IEnumerable is an interface and ToList is a query eith concrete class. this link will help you to understand the difference => `https://stackoverflow.com/a/17449053/5514820`

Comment: Thanks very much for the link, I'll look at that now.

Comment: this will also help you to understand => https://stackoverflow.com/a/23033688/5514820 and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/ienumerable-vs-list and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work

Answer (score 4):

Re-order things so that you GroupBy and then Select each group into your desired object:

```
...
.GroupBy(x => x.consigdests.consignment)
.Select(x => new GoodInWarehouseBM
{
    pallet_identifier = x.Key,
    shipment_items = x.Select(i => new GoodInWarehouseBM.ShipmentItems
    {
        sku = x.productcodess.variantcode,
        stock_qty = x.consigliness.issueqty,
        description = x.products.proddesc
    }
});
```

You may have to fiddle with the syntax a little as I am not used to the SQL-like LINQ syntax. I would recommend learning to use the lambda based syntax wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will start to re write lambda, i just find SQL like syntax easier to read personally especially with so many joins.

Comment: When you're doing joins in the c# syntax it's typical to use navigation properties. This gets me by in 99% of cases, but I do agree that when I absolutely must perform a JOIN that it reads better in the SQL syntax than with the clunky GroupJoin function.